# Quadratic Reciprocity Law

Tags: number-theory

Can anyone help me find the solution to the quadratic equation $y^2 \equiv 1+8q^{p-1} (mod \ p)$ where p and q are primes such that p>q?

I did this by trial and error but does anyone know a systematic solution to solve this quadratic equation?

Comment: Well... $q^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so...

Comment: Using this, we are left with $y^2-9 \equiv 0 (mod p)$. Is there a way to generalize that values of $y$ that satisfies this equation?

Comment: Yes.  The square root of $9$ is $\pm 3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2\equiv1+8q^{p-1}\bmod p.$$ Now, $p$ is prime, so by Fermat's little theorem $q^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$. So $$y^2\equiv 1+8=9\bmod p,$$ and so $$y\equiv \pm 3\bmod p.$$

Comment: *Revising for a number theory exam next week; so just using questions like these to test myself.* So feel free to ignore this if you already have the answer (which I see the comments have taken care of).